# How to check floating point equality without knowing the rounding digits in the floats?

Tags: python, floating-point

I am clustering a raster file with WGS 84 (lat/lon co-ordinates). One pixel on the grid is a square of side (1/3600: which is 1 arc-second). The grid has a massive number of pixels. Therefore I wanted to split the jobs up so they can be parallelized. I ran a script that divides the entire grid as 1585*1585 squares of pixels, it produces the x_min x_max, y_min and y_max (I stored these values in a pandas dataframe) of the square and then splits the job according to them and submits the jobs. I made the mistake of identifying the resulting output by those co-ordinates(The files are named like this Linalg_Kenya-33.95875-34.39875-3.6965277777777774-4.136527777777777.csv). Now when I go to check which jobs are done based on my dataframe, using a script that constructs a filename such as the one above using the dataframe columns I get a few matches (~80). When I see using a glob like Linalg_Kenya*.csv. there are (~300) files. I am assuming this is due to the floating point error when I construct the string to glob in the script. How would I go about doing this?

I have tried math.isclose, but am not sure what abs I should set due to the large number of decimal places.

I also tried the method mentioned in https://www.quora.com/How-does-one-correctly-compare-two-floats-in-Python-to-test-if-they-are-equal
But this went the other way and matched everything with everything.

```
dist = 1/3600
x_start = 33.9129166666666677
y_start = 5.4573611111111111
for x in range(18):
    x_mi = x_start+(1585*x*dist)
    x_ma = x_mi+(1584*dist)
    for y in range(23):
        y_ma = y_start-(1585*y*dist)
        y_mi = y_ma-(1584*dist)
        x_min.append(x_mi1)
        y_min.append(y_mi1)
        x_max.append(x_ma1)
        y_max.append(y_ma1)
```

This is how I generated the values in the first place. I stored them in a pandas dataframe. I access them by using iterrows and then generating the glob string for each row.

Comment: You have not stated a proper question. The only sentence in your post with a question mark is “How would I go about doing this?” But it is not clear what “this” is. The prior sentence is about an assumption you make about floating-point error. The sentence before that is about observing the number of data files you have. The sentence before that is about getting “matches” when constructing file names. What is the “this” that you want to go about? What is the **specific** thing that fails?

Comment: Are you perhaps finding that the file names generated with the coordinates calculated in one way are different from the names calculated in another way? If so, why not calculate the names in the same way in both cases?

Comment: Why do you “construct the string to glob in the script”? If you are calculating a coordinates for a file name, would not that give you the exact file name, not a pattern you need to match to find the file?

Comment: In any case, the `x` and `y` values of the code in the question can be recovered from the calculated coordinates by inverting the arithmetic and rounding to an integer. E.g., given a file with 4.136527777777777 for its y minimum, invert `y_ma = y_start-(1585*y*dist)` to `y = (y_start-y_ma)/1585/dist` and then round the result to the nearest integer (which produces 3 in this case). The rounding errors in these simple calculations will be small, so the original integer will be recovered without error.

Comment: Conversely, if you take a value slightly less than 1/2, say .49, and calculate `1585*.49*dist`, you have a threshold for comparison of calculated y coordinates.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Once I divided into the boxes. The output of the script I ran on each box would be saved as Linalg_Kenya-33.95875-34.39875-3.6965277777777774-4.136527777777777.csv where each value separated by - is xmin, xmax, ymin and ymax respectively. The only thing tying back the output to my original dataframe are these 4 params. If I know that 300 jobs are completed and I search for the corresponding files I should get 300 matches. But I only get a few ~80. Even though I can see the files present. My question is why is this happening and how do I solve it?

Comment: Also you are right I am not globbing the string I am constructing the string and searching for matching files using the glob module in python. The co-ordinates are stored in a pandas dataframe with the dtype as float64. Thank you for your help!

Comment: When creating the names, explicitly limit the number of digits after the decimal point, rounding or truncating probably doesn't matter.  So, instead of `Linalg_Kenya-33.95875-3.696527777777774`..., work with `Linalg_Kenya-33.9588-34.3988-3.6965-4.1365` instead.  As a practical matter, four digits provides a granularity (or resolution) of less than 11 metres on the Earth.

Comment: @Wallyk you are absolutely right. I have corrected my method after learning from this. But the outputs that have been generated already have a significant amount of compute time behind them. I was looking for a way to recover them. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you read the python docs on floating point arithmetic and its limitations.  If you haven't: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html.
It is good background into the issue and will point out things to be wary of.

As far as your specific problem with floating point, perhaps the decimal library can be of help: https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#module-decimal. According to the documentation above, "For use cases which require exact decimal representation, try using the decimal module which implements decimal arithmetic suitable for accounting applications and high-precision applications." This should therefore provide the tools you need to alleviate the decimal precision issues and construct the proper search queries for globbing.

Another option to consider would be calculating everything using integers instead, but this would likely only mask the problem "most" of the time by reducing the number of decimal places required for your calculations.

Comment: Given `dist = 1/3600`, decimal will not avoid all problems. 1/3600 is no more representable in decimal floating-point than 1/10 is in binary floating-point.